# Attempting to use GPT-4 & LangChain, can't nodejs -- npm run dev not working

Tags: python, npm, chatbot, openai-api, langchain

trying to use gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain.

went through the steps as noted on this link: https://github.com/mayooear/gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain

get to the last step, there was no docs folder so i created one and added a pdf.
try running the command npm run ingest and npm run dev, both give me this error.

here is the error (for both commands):

```
    `C:\Users\stef\Downloads\gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain-main>npm run dev
    npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\stef\Downloads\gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain-main/package.json
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 506 while parsing '{
    npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "gpt4-langchain-pdf-chatbot"'
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\stef\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-14T01_48_55_458Z-debug-0.log`
```

any ideas how to fix? im a noob coder. will attach some more info below.

api keys are for sure working.

```
node -v
v20.1.0
npm -v
9.6.4
```

completely clueless. if anyone can help i would be very grateful.

complete error log file:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.6.4
2 info using node@v20.1.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\stef\Downloads\gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain-main\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\stef\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\stef\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 6ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 6ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm run dev
21 verbose argv "run" "dev"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\stef\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-14T01_48_55_458Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\stef\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-14T01_48_55_458Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 6ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 18ms
31 timing command:run Completed in 3ms
32 verbose stack JSONParseError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 506 while parsing '{
32 verbose stack   "name": "gpt4-langchain-pdf-chatbot"'
32 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json-fast\lib\index.js:7:61
32 verbose stack     at async RunScript.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\run-script.js:73:19)
32 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:89:5)
33 verbose cwd C:\Users\stef\Downloads\gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain-main
34 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
35 verbose node v20.1.0
36 verbose npm  v9.6.4
37 error code EJSONPARSE
38 error path C:\Users\stef\Downloads\gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain-main/package.json
39 error JSON.parse Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 506 while parsing '{
39 error JSON.parse   "name": "gpt4-langchain-pdf-chatbot"'
40 error JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
40 error JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
41 verbose exit 1
42 timing npm Completed in 37ms
43 verbose code 1
44 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\stef\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-14T01_48_55_458Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain with Node `v18.16.0`, and it worked very well. You can try using `v18.16.0`. BTW, I don't recommend using a too higher Node version in your project.